# Why does CPU run faster than GPU in this code?

Tags: matlab, loops, gpu

I'm trying to speed up my computing by using `gpuArray`. However, that's not the case for my code below.

```
for i=1:10
    calltest;
end

function [t1,t2]=calltest
N=10;
tic
u=gpuArray(rand(1,N).^(1./[N:-1:1]));
t1=toc
tic
u2=rand(1,N).^(1./[N:-1:1]);
t2=toc
end
```

where I get

```
t1 =

   4.8445e-05


t2 =

   1.4369e-05
```

I have an Nvidia GTX850M graphic card. Am I using `gpuArray` incorrectly? This code is wrapped inside a function, and the function is called by a loop thousands of times.

Comment: Note that `timeit` will return a more reliable result.

Comment: You are copying the final result to GPU, which is not what you want. You should rather do something like `u=gpuArray(rand(1,N)).^(1./gpuArray([N:-1:1])));` (_untested_)

Comment: Have a look at the [`gpuArray`](https://mathworks.com/help/distcomp/gpuarray.html#bsni4_e-3) documentation.

Comment: actually it's much slower using the method you suggested. I edited the code, It seem loop and calling the function makes it slower when using `gpuArray`! Any idea?

Comment: Transferring data to the GPU may take some time. You can to only time the calculation time by transferring it beforehand.

Comment: Yes, one may pre-load data onto GPU, but the net effect of Amdahl Law speedup calculation will be skewed, if this intrinsic part of the process is administratively subtracted from the overall experiment timing -- both setup  & tear-down overheads are fair to be calculated ( if the speedup figures are not to become principally useless, except just for one's Sales & PR product-promotion campaigns ). The real-world computing measures a fair run from the very start to the very finish-line, as do all hurdle athletic races, don't they? If the intermediate results are made & kept on GPU, no problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why?
Because there is both
a) a small problem-scale 
&
b) not a "mathematically-dense" GPU-kernel

The method of comparison is blurring the root-cause of the problem

### Step 0: separate data-set ( a vector ) creation from section-under-test:

```
N = 10;
R = rand( 1, N );
tic; < a-gpu-based-computing-section>; GPU_t = toc
tic; c = R.^( 1. / [N:-1:1] );         CPU_t = toc
```

### Step 1: test the scaling:

trying just 10 elements, will not make the observation clear, as ***an overhead-naive* [formulation of Amdahl Law](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18374629/3)** does not explicitly emphasise the added time, spent on CPU-based GPU-kernel assembly & transport + ( CPU-to-GPU + GPU-to-CPU ) data-handling phases. These add-on phases may get negligibly small, if compared to
**a)** an indeed large-scale vector / matrix GPU-kernel processing, which N ~10 obviously is not
or
**b)** an indeed "mathematically-dense" GPU-kernel processing, which `R.^()` obviously is not
so,
do not blame the GPU-computing for having acquired a must-do part ( the overheads ) as it cannot get working without this prior add-ons in time ( and CPU may, during the same amount of time, produce the final result - Q.E.D. )

### Fine-grain measurement, per each of the CPU-GPU-CPU-workflow sections:

```
N = 10;                                     %% 100, 1000, 10000, 100000, ..
tic; CPU_hosted     = rand( N, 'single' );  %% 'double'
CPU_gen_RAND        = toc

tic; GPU_hosted_IN1 = gpuArray( CPU_hosted );
GPU_xfer_h2d        = toc

tic; GPU_hosted_IN2 = rand( N, 'gpuArray' );
GPU_gen__h2d        = toc

tic; <kernel-generation-with-might-be-lazy-eval-deferred-xfer-setup>;
GPU_kernel_AssyExec = toc

tic; CPU_hosted_RES = gather( GPU_hosted_RES );
GPU_xfer_d2h        = toc
```

Comment: Are you sure you are performing any calculation on the GPU?

Comment: While I am not sure, if MathWorks implementation tests the resulting GPU-kernel for having become effectively a NOP / identity-operator on instructed data-set(s), I am pretty sure both the **a)** and the **b)** hold true. Yet the code-related and data-related overheads of the GPU-kernel + ( h2d & d2h ) data-transfers remain in place. Your point is systematically correct, while I doubt ( due to an immense computational costs thereof ) that MathWorks perform a pre-test, effectively pre-validating all of the GPU-kernels do output an identity on each data-to be input element (b4 shortcut GPU-step)

Comment: You are not. `gpuArray` puts things in the GPU. Your code does first  `R.^( 1. / [N:-1:1] )` and then puts the result in the GPU. You are right in what you say, but wrong in your code