# Why adding numbers on a single CPU core is 6 times faster than on a 32-core GPU?

Tags: swift, gpu, metal, apple-m1

I'm benchmarking GPU computing using Metal running on an Apple M1 Max's 32-core GPU. The test task is to add an array of 1 billion numbers to another array of the same size. For that, I'm using Xcode 13.1 to run the project in the Release build configuration (optimized for performance) and with "Debug executable" turned off.

I've got two files:

**compute.metal**:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

kernel void addition_compute_function(constant float *arr1        [[ buffer(0) ]],
                                      constant float *arr2        [[ buffer(1) ]],
                                      device   float *resultArray [[ buffer(2) ]],
                                               uint   index [[ thread_position_in_grid ]]) {
    resultArray[index] = arr1[index] + arr2[index];
}
```

**main.swift**:

```swift
import MetalKit

main()

func main() {
    let count = 1_000_000_000

    let array1 = getArray(count: count)
    let array2 = Array(array1.reversed())

    cpuWay(count: count, arr1: array1, arr2: array2)
    print()
    gpuWay(count: count, arr1: array1, arr2: array2)
    print()
}

func cpuWay(count: Int, arr1: [Float], arr2: [Float]) {
    var result: [Float] = .init(repeating: 0.0, count: count)

    print("CPU way:")
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

    for i in 0..<count {
        result[i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i]
    }

    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    print("Time elapsed \(String(format: "%.05f", timeElapsed)) seconds")
}

func gpuWay(count: Int, arr1: [Float], arr2: [Float]) {
    guard let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() else { fatalError() }
    guard let library = device.makeDefaultLibrary() else { fatalError() }
    guard let function = library.makeFunction(name: "addition_compute_function") else { fatalError() }
    let length = count*MemoryLayout<Float>.size
    let arr1Buff = device.makeBuffer(bytes: arr1, length: length, options: .storageModeShared)
    let arr2Buff = device.makeBuffer(bytes: arr2, length: length, options: .storageModeShared)
    let resultBuff = device.makeBuffer(length: length, options: .storageModeShared)

    guard let commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue() else { fatalError() }
    guard let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer() else { fatalError() }
    guard let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder() else { fatalError() }
    let additionComputePipelineState = try! device.makeComputePipelineState(function: function)
    commandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(additionComputePipelineState)
    commandEncoder.setBuffer(arr1Buff, offset: 0, index: 0)
    commandEncoder.setBuffer(arr2Buff, offset: 0, index: 1)
    commandEncoder.setBuffer(resultBuff, offset: 0, index: 2)
    let threadsPerGrid = MTLSize(width: count, height: 1, depth: 1)
    let maxThreadsPerThreadgroup = additionComputePipelineState.maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup // 1024
    let threadsPerThreadgroup = MTLSize(width: maxThreadsPerThreadgroup, height: 1, depth: 1)
    commandEncoder.dispatchThreads(threadsPerGrid, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerThreadgroup)
    commandEncoder.endEncoding()
    commandBuffer.commit()

    print("GPU way:")
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

    commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()

    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    print("Time elapsed \(String(format: "%.05f", timeElapsed)) seconds")
}

func getArray(count: Int) -> [Float] {
    var result: [Float] = .init(repeating: 0.0, count: count)
    for i in 0..<count { result[i] = Float(i) }
    return result
}
```

And the results are:

```
CPU way:
Time elapsed 0.35217 seconds

GPU way:
Time elapsed 2.10124 seconds
```

Which makes computations on a single CPU core look 6 times more performant than on a 32-core GPU.

Why is that? Am I using all the GPU cores?

**EDIT:**
This question is about Metal, not Matlab.
It's not a duplicate of
[Why does CPU run faster than GPU in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45863019/why-does-cpu-run-faster-than-gpu-in-this-code)

Comment: Your test comparison is not done correctly. First of all, please remove the initialization of metal api from the gpuWay function, and then provide the result again.

Comment: @HamidYusifli It's correct because `startTime` is set to the current time after the GPU initialization is done.