# Please help me figure out why this Metal code is slower than CPU code?

Tags: swift, performance, gpu, metal, apple-m1

I'm benchmarking GPU computing using Metal running on an Apple M1 Max's 32-core GPU. The test task is to add an array of 1 billion numbers to another array of the same size. For that, I'm using Xcode 13.1 to run the project in the Release build configuration (optimized for performance) and with "Debug executable" turned off.

I've got two files:

**compute.metal**:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

kernel void addition_compute_function(constant float *arr1        [[ buffer(0) ]],
                                      constant float *arr2        [[ buffer(1) ]],
                                      device   float *resultArray [[ buffer(2) ]],
                                               uint   index [[ thread_position_in_grid ]]) {
    resultArray[index] = arr1[index] + arr2[index];
}
```

**main.swift**:

```swift
import MetalKit

main()

func main() {
    let count = 1_000_000_000

    let array1 = getArray(count: count)
    let array2 = Array(array1.reversed())

    cpuWay(count: count, arr1: array1, arr2: array2)
    print()
    gpuWay(count: count, arr1: array1, arr2: array2)
    print()
}

func cpuWay(count: Int, arr1: [Float], arr2: [Float]) {
    var result: [Float] = .init(repeating: 0.0, count: count)

    print("CPU way:")
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

    for i in 0..<count {
        result[i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i]
    }

    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    print("Time elapsed \(String(format: "%.05f", timeElapsed)) seconds")
}

func gpuWay(count: Int, arr1: [Float], arr2: [Float]) {
    guard let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice() else { fatalError() }
    guard let library = device.makeDefaultLibrary() else { fatalError() }
    guard let function = library.makeFunction(name: "addition_compute_function") else { fatalError() }
    let length = count*MemoryLayout<Float>.size
    let arr1Buff = device.makeBuffer(bytes: arr1, length: length, options: .storageModeShared)
    let arr2Buff = device.makeBuffer(bytes: arr2, length: length, options: .storageModeShared)
    let resultBuff = device.makeBuffer(length: length, options: .storageModeShared)

    guard let commandQueue = device.makeCommandQueue() else { fatalError() }
    guard let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer() else { fatalError() }
    guard let commandEncoder = commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder() else { fatalError() }
    let additionComputePipelineState = try! device.makeComputePipelineState(function: function)
    commandEncoder.setComputePipelineState(additionComputePipelineState)
    commandEncoder.setBuffer(arr1Buff, offset: 0, index: 0)
    commandEncoder.setBuffer(arr2Buff, offset: 0, index: 1)
    commandEncoder.setBuffer(resultBuff, offset: 0, index: 2)
    let threadsPerGrid = MTLSize(width: count, height: 1, depth: 1)
    let maxThreadsPerThreadgroup = additionComputePipelineState.maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup // 1024
    let threadsPerThreadgroup = MTLSize(width: maxThreadsPerThreadgroup, height: 1, depth: 1)
    commandEncoder.dispatchThreads(threadsPerGrid, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerThreadgroup)
    commandEncoder.endEncoding()
    commandBuffer.commit()

    print("GPU way:")
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

    commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()

    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    print("Time elapsed \(String(format: "%.05f", timeElapsed)) seconds")
}

func getArray(count: Int) -> [Float] {
    var result: [Float] = .init(repeating: 0.0, count: count)
    for i in 0..<count { result[i] = Float(i) }
    return result
}
```

And the results are:

```
CPU way:
Time elapsed 0.35217 seconds

GPU way:
Time elapsed 2.10124 seconds
```

Why is that? Am I using all the GPU cores?

**Please note**
This question is about **Metal**, not Matlab. It's not a duplicate of
[Why does CPU run faster than GPU in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45863019/why-does-cpu-run-faster-than-gpu-in-this-code)
In that question the OP is testing just 10 elements, this code is testing 1 billion elements.

Comment: GPUs work the same way regardless of what language you use. You should learn the basics of GPU and computer architecture. You cannot just parallelise any sort of work and expect it to be faster...

Comment: @DávidPásztor Metal is an API, not a language. And learning about the basics of GPU is exactly what I'm doing asking this question.

Comment: I've learned much from @DávidPásztor, he's one of the best active GPU/Metal/CoreImage posters here. Maybe the issue is *how* you are using the GPU? I'm still learning how to use Metal (which YES, is an API) but it's also tightly tied to Apple's languages of Obj-C and Swift. The biggest question I have is your use of `commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()`. Is this the bottleneck?

Comment: Could you please benchmark a second run without the initial setup of the pipeline state? I assume Metal will be faster once you only need to copy buffers and encode the commands. Also, a simple addition is probably not the best benchmark since that can also be heavily optimized on CPU using vector instructions.