# Determine number of threads for element-wise array addition in Metal

Tags: swift, metal, accelerate-framework

In this example there are two large 1D arrays of size `n`. The arrays are added together element-wise to calculate a 1D results array using the Accelerate `vDSP.add()` function and a Metal GPU compute kernel `adder()`.

```swift
// Size of each array
private let n = 5_000_000

// Create two random arrays of size n
private var array1 = (1...n).map{ _ in Float.random(in: 1...10) }
private var array2 = (1...n).map{ _ in Float.random(in: 1...10) }

// Add two arrays using Accelerate vDSP
addAccel(array1, array2)

// Add two arrays using Metal on the GPU
addMetal(array1, array2)
```

The **Accelerate** code is shown below:

```swift
import Accelerate

func addAccel(_ arr1: [Float], _ arr2: [Float]) {
    
    let tic = DispatchTime.now().uptimeNanoseconds

    // Add two arrays and store results
    let y = vDSP.add(arr1, arr2)
    
    // Print out elapsed time
    let toc = DispatchTime.now().uptimeNanoseconds
    let elapsed = Float(toc - tic) / 1_000_000_000
    print("\nAccelerate vDSP elapsed time is \(elapsed) s")
    
    // Print out some results
    for i in 0..<3 {
        let a1 = String(format: "%.4f", arr1[i])
        let a2 = String(format: "%.4f", arr2[i])
        let y = String(format: "%.4f", y[i])
        print("\(a1) + \(a2) = \(y)")
    }
}
```

The **Metal** code is shown below:

```swift
import MetalKit

private func setupMetal(arr1: [Float], arr2: [Float]) -> (MTLCommandBuffer?, MTLBuffer?) {
    
    // Get the Metal GPU device
    let device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice()
    
    // Queue for sending commands to the GPU
    let commandQueue = device?.makeCommandQueue()
    
    // Get our Metal GPU function
    let gpuFunctionLibrary = device?.makeDefaultLibrary()
    let adderGpuFunction = gpuFunctionLibrary?.makeFunction(name: "adder")
    
    var adderComputePipelineState: MTLComputePipelineState!
    do {
        adderComputePipelineState = try device?.makeComputePipelineState(function: adderGpuFunction!)
    } catch {
      print(error)
    }
    
    // Create the buffers to be sent to the GPU from our arrays
    let count = arr1.count

    let arr1Buff = device?.makeBuffer(bytes: arr1,
                                      length: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * count,
                                      options: .storageModeShared)
    
    let arr2Buff = device?.makeBuffer(bytes: arr2,
                                      length: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * count,
                                      options: .storageModeShared)

    let resultBuff = device?.makeBuffer(length: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * count,
                                        options: .storageModeShared)
    
    // Create a buffer to be sent to the command queue
    let commandBuffer = commandQueue?.makeCommandBuffer()
    
    // Create an encoder to set values on the compute function
    let commandEncoder = commandBuffer?.makeComputeCommandEncoder()
    commandEncoder?.setComputePipelineState(adderComputePipelineState)
    
    // Set the parameters of our GPU function
    commandEncoder?.setBuffer(arr1Buff, offset: 0, index: 0)
    commandEncoder?.setBuffer(arr2Buff, offset: 0, index: 1)
    commandEncoder?.setBuffer(resultBuff, offset: 0, index: 2)
    
    // Figure out how many threads we need to use for our operation
    let threadsPerGrid = MTLSize(width: count, height: 1, depth: 1)
    let maxThreadsPerThreadgroup = adderComputePipelineState.maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup
    let threadsPerThreadgroup = MTLSize(width: maxThreadsPerThreadgroup, height: 1, depth: 1)
    commandEncoder?.dispatchThreads(threadsPerGrid, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerThreadgroup)
    
    // Tell the encoder that it is done encoding. Now we can send this off to the GPU.
    commandEncoder?.endEncoding()
    
    return (commandBuffer, resultBuff)
}

func addMetal(_ arr1: [Float], _ arr2: [Float]) {
    
    let (commandBuffer, resultBuff) = setupMetal(arr1: arr1, arr2: arr2)
    let tic = DispatchTime.now().uptimeNanoseconds

    // Push this command to the command queue for processing
    commandBuffer?.commit()
    
    // Wait until the GPU function completes before working with any of the data
    commandBuffer?.waitUntilCompleted()
    
    // Get the pointer to the beginning of our data
    let count = arr1.count
    var resultBufferPointer = resultBuff?.contents().bindMemory(to: Float.self, capacity: MemoryLayout<Float>.size * count)
    
    // Print out elapsed time
    let toc = DispatchTime.now().uptimeNanoseconds
    let elapsed = Float(toc - tic) / 1_000_000_000
    print("\nMetal GPU elapsed time is \(elapsed) s")
    
    // Print out the results
    for i in 0..<3 {
        let a1 = String(format: "%.4f", arr1[i])
        let a2 = String(format: "%.4f", arr2[i])
        let y = String(format: "%.4f", Float(resultBufferPointer!.pointee))
        print("\(a1) + \(a2) = \(y)")
        resultBufferPointer = resultBufferPointer?.advanced(by: 1)
    }
}
```

```cpp
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

kernel void adder(
                  constant float *array1 [[ buffer(0) ]],
                  constant float *array2 [[ buffer(1) ]],
                  device float *result [[ buffer(2) ]],
                  uint index [[ thread_position_in_grid ]])
{
    result[index] = array1[index] + array2[index];
}
```

Results from running the above code on a 2019 MacBook Pro are given below. Specs for the laptop are 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7, 32 GB 2667 MHz DDR4, Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB, and AMD Radeon Pro 5500M.

```
Accelerate vDSP elapsed time is 0.004532601 s
7.8964 + 6.3815 = 14.2779
9.3661 + 8.9641 = 18.3301
4.5389 + 8.5737 = 13.1126

Metal GPU elapsed time is 0.012219718 s
7.8964 + 6.3815 = 14.2779
9.3661 + 8.9641 = 18.3301
4.5389 + 8.5737 = 13.1126
```

Based on the elapsed times, the Accelerate function is faster than the Metal compute function. I think this is because I did not properly define the threads. How do I determine the optimum number of threads per grid and threads per thread group for this example?

```swift
// Figure out how many threads we need to use for our operation
let threadsPerGrid = MTLSize(width: count, height: 1, depth: 1)
let maxThreadsPerThreadgroup = adderComputePipelineState.maxTotalThreadsPerThreadgroup
let threadsPerThreadgroup = MTLSize(width: maxThreadsPerThreadgroup, height: 1, depth: 1)
commandEncoder?.dispatchThreads(threadsPerGrid, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadsPerThreadgroup)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does CPU run faster than GPU in this code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45863019/why-does-cpu-run-faster-than-gpu-in-this-code)

Comment: @HamidYusifli This does not answer my question. Your suggested question is for Matlab and not Swift/Metal. I updated my question to better explain the problem. I'm basically trying to figure out how to properly define the threads for Metal.

Comment: I know that the question I suggested is about Matlab, but the answer is also suitable for Metal. Anyways I upvoted your question, I hope you will find the answer to it.

Answer (score -1):

For metal you are measuring time in both computation and data transfer from GPU to CPU and also creating array on CPU.

You should use [addcompletedhandler](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcommandbuffer/1442997-addcompletedhandler) for gpu compution time